# GetJSON and using a Show More link

Tags: json, facebook, getjson

I'm using getJSON to get data from the facebook pages api, and it works just fine, using this code:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('url',function(json){

        $.each(json.data,function(i,fb){

           var output='';

        //here I add to output, as this example line:


            output += '<div"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='+fb.from.id+'>'+fb.from.name+'</a>';


           $("#results").append(output);

    });
});
```

However, what I'd like to do is similar to what facebook does in it's social plug in where it starts off with 5 entries and has a Show More link, which when clicked, brings in 5 more entries.

Is there a way to do this by altering the code I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sure there is. Do you want to fetch the other results when a user clicks the "more link" to save bandwidth or is it **OK to fetch it at the same time**? *(async vs sync)*

This answer considers the bold text:

```
output += '<div' + (i >= 5 ? ' style="display: none;"' : '') + '><a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=' + fb.from.id +'>'+fb.from.name+'</a></div>';
```

*Oh, and check that line in your code, you had a syntax error and an unmatched div. Also you should have quotation marks around your HTML element's attributes.*

For showing the links when the more link is clicked you could do something like:

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    // Find the closest ancestor which is a parent of both
    // the more link and the actual results list
    var $parent = $(this).closest('.parentSelector');
    $('.listSelector', $parent).children().show();
    return false; // Don't follow the link
});
```

The parts with the parent stuff above is for the case when you have multiple such results list on the same page and you need to separate them. If you don't need it, here is a simpler variant:

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#results').children().show(); // Show all other list items
    return false; // Don't follow the link
});
```

Comment: Thanks...I could do it either way (async or sync)

Comment: Also, how would I limit the first load (before they click the more link) to show only, say 5 results..such that when they click more, they get the rest?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the Facebook API, but there might be parameters you can add to the URL, like "limit" and "offset", perhaps?

Comment: I've looked an not found any parameters..the only way I know to limit the feed is with   if (i==5){ return false};

Comment: Then this solution might be the best choice for you.

Comment: Oh, and I edited the output=... line in my answer. It was incorrect.

Comment: that is a great way to limit the output..now, just need to figure out how to trigger it to show all

Comment: Ok..figured this out, but thanks Betamos for getting me on the right track!

Comment: Great, I was away all day, but I'm glad it worked out. Don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem, it will give both you and me better reputation! :)

Comment: sure, I accepted the answer, but it requires this to make it work   $("#show-more").click(function () {
   $(".box_item").show();
   $("#show-more").hide();
        return false;
    });